# Why are the 2 key frames connected?

Tags: animation

[image]

Hello!

I have copied 1 key frame, then pasted it at an empty space.
Now when I click the new key frame, it is automatically connected to the keyframe that I copied it from.

And when I clear the pose on this key frame and propagate it, it is automatically transferred to that other key frame, too.

I don't want that.
How do I resolve this connection?

Thank you.

[Here is a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=11VZHGKm0Xo) that shows how changing one keyframe affects the other.

[image]

Comment: that's weird, if you change a keyframe it should not be replicated to the next, maybe share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: The line between the 2 keyframes just means that the keyed values are the same for both keyframes.

Comment: @Frank Ok, but I changed the values only on the one key frame.

Comment: @moonboots blend file link and video added. Thank you.

Comment: I don't know propagate but it looks like it saves the transform you make on the selected bone and paste it to the next keyframe if it's the same (or else, depending on the option you choose in the Operator box), maybe tell what you want to do exactly?

Comment: @moonboots I wanted to add an initial frame and put it in t-pose. So I moved all keyframes one tick to the right, then I selected the keyframe at position 2, clicked "Copy", went to the (empty) position 1 and clicked "Paste". I selected the newly added keyframe and clicked "Clear transform", "Propagate".

Comment: if you want to create a T pose but want to keep a copy of the first pose, select, duplicate the first keyframes with shift D and move them to the next frame, select the first keyframes, press alt R alt G alt S and keyframe?

Comment: @moonboots If I am in Pose Mode, and I select a keyframe and press Shift D with Blender 2.9, it does something strange... It says something about Delta and locks the mouse pointer somehow. Can you try it yourself?

Comment: @moonboots Your approach is like mine, I think. It doesn't change anything: The duplicated key frame is still linked.

Comment: @tmighty, fyi, I don't get the point (maybe I've not understood what you want to do). If from your file I delete keyframe at 2,then duplicate the one at 1 and place it at 2, they are linked as same. But now if I come back at 1, clear transform and insert keyframe, all seems fine. So? Am I wrong... what do you want to do?

Comment: @lemon Yeah!! Your approach works. Thank you! I still need time to figure out what you're doing that I didn't do. I have uploaded a video of the new updated approach here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9gh7Z8QjGnY It works.

Answer (score 2):

When you see a line like that between two keyframes it means that there is no change: the values for the keyframes are the same. The keyframe is duplicated.